# Marcar "Isto resolveu o meu problema"

Tags: debate

Pessoal tenho a pergunta abaixo que foi feita em 10/03, e outra pessoa fez a pergunta parecida em 16/03 e a solução desta nova pergunta resolveu o meu problema.

Gostaria de saber se "Isto resolveu o meu problema", terei alguma punição, pois a minha pergunta não é duplicada.

[Assinar NFs-e em C# gera erro Elemento Reference mal formado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117568/assinar-nfs-e-em-c-gera-erro-elemento-reference-mal-formado/)

Comment: Coloque a pergunta que resolveu seu problema.

Comment: Não se preocupe, a sua não é duplicata, e sim, a outra, pois a sua é mais antiga, apesar de não ter respostas.

Comment: @Randrade http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118481/assinatura-digital-de-lote-de-rps-nfs-e-erro-elemento-de-refer%C3%AAncia-mal-forma

Comment: @DiegoF nem sempre, muitas vezes a mais antiga pode ser duplicada pois a mais nova tem resposta e a antiga não, no caso aqui do Marlon parece ser isto, pois a outra pergunta tem a solução para o problema dele.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento do ponto de vista cronológico, não faria muito sentido uma pergunta antiga ser duplicata de uma pergunta recente, mas olhando por esse lado, até que faz sentido, dai quem for redirecionado pra pergunta dele, terá a referencia da pergunta atual com respostas. Bom saber hehe

Comment: @DiegoF sim se for seguir este sentido, contudo o conteúdo tem mais "valor" que o "tempo", não é a primeira vez que vejo isso =)

Comment: Eu tb não, @GuilhermeNascimento : [Fechar a pergunta mais antiga como duplicata ou não?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3874/3117). E concordo com a resposta do Sergio.

Comment: @Math estava procurando o link :D obrigado

Comment: Marlon, ter uma pergunta marcada como duplicada não é uma punição. Não são retirados pontos, nem nada do tipo. A marcação serve apenas pra manter as coisas organizadas e certificar de que todo mundo que encontrar qualquer uma das perguntas pode ter acesso rápido à resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Marlon, ter uma pergunta marcada como duplicada não é uma punição. Não são retirados pontos, nem nada do tipo.

O site recebe dezenas (quase uma centena) de perguntas, todos os dias. É certo que, eventualment, uma pergunta feita hoje vai ser basicamente a mesma de uma pergunta feita há 2 anos atrás. E quando isso acontecer, a melhor coisa é que todo mundo com o mesmo problema tenha acesso à mesma resposta. E é pra isso que a marcação como "duplicada" serve. Pra manter as coisas organizadas.

Tudo que ela diz é que outra pessoa teve o mesmo problema que você, e já encontrou uma resposta que pode te ajudar.